# Angular 5 - Display a table vertically by changing the HTML format only

Tags: angular

I am trying to flip my horizontal table to a vertical table by only modifying the HTML file.

Here is the live code that I am currently working on: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdame7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Arrays:

```
public header: Array<string>;
public colors: Array<string>;
public cars: Array<string>;
public numbers: Array<string>;

header = {"COLORS", "CARS", "NUMBERS"};

colors= {"Blue", "Red", "Yellow"}

cars= {"Lambo", "Porsche", "Mercedes"}

numbers= {"1", "2", "3"}
```

Expected Result:

```
COLORS   CARS     NUMBERS

Blue     Lambo      1

Red      Porsche    2

Yellow   Mercedes   3
```

Comment: this is css related problem, nothing to do with HTML

Comment: oh, can you give me some tips on how I should approach this in CSS ?

Comment: If you are trying to achieve the result like @yer posted, its right. I thought that you have 4 "labels" and you want to display them in a vertical way, so this one you need css. If you just need to have table with rows and cols, the answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let head of _types.header"> {{head}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let m of _types.colors">
            <td>
                {{m}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I just updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdame7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared.service.ts

Is there a dynamic way to display a table with my current class/service setup with an angular component or something that can make my life easier for a more complex table. I want to be able to fill up each column by its own array

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to get. Pleasepost the sample of what you actually want in the question

Comment: I have updated the main topic. With an example of what I want.

Comment: How would you add a second column with that method? This is how I had it before adding the extra arrays. You posted the same link as mine In the OP.

Comment: are you having different arrays for each column?